# How to pass, and loop, an indetermined array to a function in VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, function

My function takes in a range, say risk-free interest rates, and produces an array of discount factors. The issue seems to be in the loop, threefold:

(a) calling a fn on an array,
(b) specifying the array points,
(c) using the loop i as a fn parameter.

Is the best way to use a loop around each array(point i), or can the full array be populated by simply calling in a function?

```
Function CreateDiscArray(RFR_array As Range)

    Dim MyArray() As Variant
    MyArray = RFR_array

    Dim xDimRate As Integer
    xDimRate = UBound(MyArray, 1)

    Dim TempArray() As Variant
    For i = 1 To xDimRate Step 1
        TempArray(i, 1) = DiscFact(MyArray(i), i)
    Next i

    CreateDiscArray() = TempArray()
End Function
```

.

```
Function DiscFact(Rate, Tenor)
    If Tenor < 1 Then DiscFact = (1 + Tenor * Rate)
    If Tenor >= 1 Then DiscFact = (1 + Rate) ^ (-Tenor)
End Function
```

i.e. is it possible to just call, without the loop:

```
CreateDiscArray = DiscFact(MyArray(,1), 1 to xDimRate)
```

Comment: In a word, no.  It seems like you're looking for something like a lambda function, which VBA doesn't offer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some problems with your original code

- You're not using `Option Explicit`, so you don't know that `i` is undeclared.
- You're not dimensioning the `TempArray`, so your code can't assign to its indexes.
- You're referencing `myArray(i)` which will fail as there are 2 dimensions, so you must use `myArray(i,1)`.
- You're using the `i` counter (which is 1-based) as the tenor. That's a poor design choice as your tenors won't always be consistent lengths, and you can expect to have many short-dated tenors. Furthermore, that's a bug, because `i >= 1` will *always* be `TRUE`

So, to make your original functions *workable code*:

```
Option Explicit

Function CreateDiscArray(RFR_array As Range)

    Dim MyArray() As Variant
    MyArray = RFR_array.Value

    Dim xDimRate As Integer
    xDimRate = UBound(MyArray, 1)

    ReDim TempArray(LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray), LBound(MyArray, 2) To UBound(MyArray, 2)) As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To xDimRate Step 1
        TempArray(i, 1) = DiscFact(MyArray(i, 1), i)
    Next i

    CreateDiscArray = TempArray
End Function

Function DiscFact(Rate, Tenor)
    'BUG: Tenor will always be >= 1
    If Tenor < 1 Then DiscFact = (1 + Tenor * Rate)
    If Tenor >= 1 Then DiscFact = (1 + Rate) ^ (-Tenor)
End Function
```

But that's not your question. As others have pointed out, VBA doesn't support anything natively, but you're using Excel, so you do have some options:

Firstly, let's fix the Tenor bug by adding a range of `tenors` in addition to the `rates`. Tenors are in `A1:A3` and rates are in `B1:B3`. We can use an array formula in `C1:C3` as `=IF(A1:A3<1,1+A1:A3*B1:B3,(1+B1:B3)^(-A1:A3))`

```
    A   |   B  |   C
--+-----|------|-------------------------------------------------
1 | .5  | 99   | {=IF(A1:A3<1,1+A1:A3*B1:B3,(1+B1:B3)^(-A1:A3))}
2 | 1   | 97   | 
3 | 2   | 95   |
```

And, if you name named ranges as Tenor and Rate, you can redefine the array formula as `=IF(Tenor<1,1+Tenor*Rate,(1+Rate)^(-Tenor))`

If you really want this solution to be in VBA, you'll need to change your function signature to accept tenor *and* rate ranges, and then use `Application.Evaluate` along with a constructed formula, to get an array of the results.

With a clumsy solution that doesn't care for sheets or workbooks:

```
Public Function DiscFactor(rates As Range, tenors As Range) As Variant

  Dim Rate As String
  Dim Tenor As String
  Rate = rates.Address
  Tenor = tenors.Address

  DiscFactor = Application.Evaluate("=IF(" & Tenor & "<1,1+" & Tenor & "*" & Rate & ",(1+" & Rate & ")^(-" & Tenor & "))")

End Function
```

Comment: Even better would be to define tenors as months, and change the test to `Tenor < 12`. That works for short-dated tenors down to month granularity, and long-dated 25 year rates

Comment: But... meta-code that generates VBA code and executes it on the fly is so much more fun!

Comment: But.... But meta code that creates a VBA proc that creates a Python script and send it to a PHP server for evaluation as json and convert back to array with custom parser written in a BAT file?

Comment: can't try it, but I think something like this should work too `CreateDiscArray  = [DiscFact(A1:A3, B1:B3)]`, and I would replace `Application.Evaluate` with `rates.Worksheet.Evaluate` https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/evaluate-functions-and-formulas-fun-how-to-make-excels-evaluate-method-twice-as-fast/

Comment: @Slai - yes, something like that would work, but you'd have to hard code the addresses into the VBA text. You couldn't use the addresses of the provided ranges.